# Different sign-up routes for different devise users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been working on creating two different types of users using devise , they have their own seperate views as the requirement needs me to do so . All's well except the routing part , whenever i mention the path of User Type 1 as /user type 1/registrations it ends up signing up as normal user . Also from the logs , it's clearly visible that the default user layout gets called .Following are my routes :-

```
 devise_for :user_type1, :controllers => { :registrations => "user_type1/registrations" }

 devise_for :user_type2, :controllers => { :registrations => "user_type2/registrations" }
```

Following are the logs -

```
Started GET "/user_type1/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-22 11:00:38 +0530
Processing by user_type1::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
   (210.0ms)  BEGIN
   (211.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered user_type1/shared/_links.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered user_type1/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (713.3ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb (107.4ms)
  Rendered application/_header-new.html.erb (117.6ms)
```

What should i do , to make devise point to the specific page for specific user . Still learning devise and how to tackle this problem , any suggestions or advice on this is most welcome . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Your problem is likely to involve the backend of your application - how are you differentiating between `user_type1` and `user_type2`?

If you have two different models - why? Remember, Rails is heavily based on the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) programming principle. You want to keep all your info structured as to be stored in a single datatable

Therefore, I would store all the users in the `User` model - and have your `user_type` field to define the type of user

--

**Setup**

I would do it this way:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users
```

This will route to the `registrations` and `sessions` controllers (for all users) - and will use all the relevant methods & dependencies for it. This wil give you the ability to define your user type in the `User` model, like so:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :set_user_type

    private

    def set_user_type
        self.type = "type" unless type
    end
end
```

--

**Redirect**

I originally read your question as "how do I redirect for different users". Obviously not the issue; but here's what I'd do anyway:

Not sure if it's valid for `Rails 3`, but you could use the [`after_sign_in_path_for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out) method in Devise:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # logic here?
end
```

Comment: Yes , i would had wanted to keep it to a single table too but the requirement was such that i had to go with the other solution . I solved it by regenerating the devise views for both models , that did it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've answered it, but here's my $.02...  I think you really wanted to scope your users.  Your said, " whenever i mention the path of User Type 1 as /user type 1/registrations it ends up signing up as normal user".  With scoping, you would be doing "/type1/user_registrations" and "/type2/user_registrations".  Scoping is well documented within the Devise guides.

EDIT on scoping:

Check out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views.  It discusses scoping between admins and users, for example.  Quoting that:

> If you have more than one Devise model in your application (such as 
>   User  and  Admin ), you will notice that Devise uses the same views
>   for all models. Fortunately, Devise offers an easy way to customize
>   views. All you need to do is set  config.scoped_views = true  inside
>   the  config/initializers/devise.rb  file.
>
> After doing so, you will be able to have views based on the role like 
>   users/sessions/new  and  admins/sessions/new . If no view is found
>
> within the scope, Devise will use the default view at 
>   devise/sessions/new . You can also use the generator to generate
>   scoped views:

```
rails generate devise:views users
```

You should read this and the next section, "[Configuring controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)".

Devise also has an extensive wiki [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki).

Comment: Can you share the link for it or some blog describing the same .Thanks a ton though, this was exactly what i was searching for :)

Comment: Edits completed above.  Please post any additional questions.  Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing on this?  Do you have additional questions?

Comment: Hey @R_G , i am stuck at the same place . What i don't understand is by copying all the files from devise/ to under user_type1 and user_type2 , it's not creating different sessions . I replaced all the user variables with type1 and type2 .

Comment: Did you enable scoping and use rails generate devise:views users to generate scoped views?  Can you post routes.rb, and your user controller(s)/models as well as any modified views?

Comment: I did post the routes for those specific devise models . Models and controllers have the same basic code generated for user , just name changed for each user .